# Getting class or id values on mouseDown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop default right click menu and make my own one, but before that on mouseDown I need to get class and id data so after when I check is it right click to open menu with specific data for that class name or id.

Now the problem is that the only thing I get for id and class values are undefined even tho I have both className and Id?

HTML:

```
      <div class='someClassName' id='someId'>someText</div>
      <div class='pss'><div class='ps' id='pS123'>Some data</div></div>
```

JS:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};

  $(document).mousedown(function(e){ 
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var clas = $(this).attr('class');
         console.log("id: "+id+" / class: "+clas);
    if(e.button==2){ 
        console.log("id: "+id+" / class: "+clas);
        if(id=="" && clas==""){
            console.log("id: "+id+" / class: "+clas);
        }else{
             if(clas=="someClassName"){
                $(document).mousemove(function(event){
                    var xPos = event.pageX;
                    var yPos = event.pageY;
                    console.log('xPos: '+xPos+'px; / yPos: '+yPos+'px;');
                });
             }
        }
        return false; 
      } 
    return true; 
  });
```

EDITED: $('body') to $(document) but I have same problem, but when I try to get some data by click on document I do get what element I clicked on by I need to check that with right click.

Comment: `var id = $(this).attr('id');` here this refer to body.

Comment: when I replace with document i have same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `$(this)` was returning the body tag because that is what you attached the click handler to. You can access what was really clicked with `e.target`. See new snippet.

```js
$('body').contextmenu(function(e) {
        var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
        var clas = $(e.target).attr('class');
        console.log("id: "+id+" / class: "+clas);
        if(id=="" && clas==""){
            console.log("id: "+id+" / class: "+clas);
        }else{
             if(clas=="someClassName"){
                $(document).mousemove(function(event){
                    var xPos = event.pageX;
                    var yPos = event.pageY;
                    console.log('xPos: '+xPos+'px; / yPos: '+yPos+'px;');
                });
             }
        }
        return false; 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='someClassName' id='someId'>someText</div>
      <div class='pss'><div class='ps' id='pS123'>Some data</div></div>
```

Comment: Its same problem even if I add document. I need to click on whole page and to check where I clicked it works with click(); but I need to check it on right click

Comment: Yes this is what I need. Thanks !

Comment: Great, glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace the $('body').mousedown with:

```
$('.youClassName').on('contextmenu', function(e)
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    className = $(this).attr('class');
    //your actions
});
```

Comment: I forgot the instruction e.preventDefault(); to prevent the browser contextmenu

Comment: But that is not what I need I need to click anywhere with right click and after that to check was I clicked to some element with specific id or class. or else if not to do nothing.

Comment: My answer does that, check the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you are handling the `body` `mousedown` event. In your handler, `this` will refer to `body`. And `body` probably does not have an `id` or `class`. You'll need to handle the specific element events. For example:

```
$('.someClassName').on('contextmenu', function(e)
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var clas = $(this).attr('class');
    console.log("id: "+id+" / class: "+clas);
    //etc
});
```

Comment: I edited, even when I replace body with document, I get same problem, also when I try same thing with click(); it works but I need it on right click...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might not understand what `this` is in the function. For event handlers, `this` (as well as jQuery's `$(this)`) refer to the element that the handler was attached. In the case of `$(document).on('mousedown', ...)`, the `$(this)` in the function will refer to the entire document. Luckily, the function you pass in has a reference to the element that was selected; the target.

## Vanilla JS

```
document.onmousedown = function(ev){
    var document = this;
    var target = ev.target;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(ev){
    var document = $(this);
    var target = ev.target;
})
```

The `target` variable is the element that was mousedowned inside of the document. From there, you can get properties of the element that was targetted.  Notice that the target will be an DOM node, you'll want to wrap it in `$()` to make it a jQuery object;

## Vanilla JS

```
document.onmousedown = function(ev){
    var document = this;
    var target = ev.target;
    var id = target.id;
    var classes = target.className.split(' ');
}
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(ev){
    var document = $(this);
    var target = $(ev.target); // jQuery wrapped target
    var id = target.attr('id');
    var classes = target.attr('class').split(' ');
})
```

I've also set the `classes` variable to a list instead of expecting a string. May not want to assume the element will always have one class.